# Search Excel column and give out the value from another cell which is in the same row but in a different column

Tags: excel

So I am trying to search for Id numbers in an excel spreadsheet. 
If it finds one of the ID numbers in the Column C it should give me a value from the same row but from Column AL and save it to a different sheet.

I have over 235 ID numbers where I want the IP addresses from. In the spreadsheet are approximately 1400 ID numbers.

Comment: So what do you have so far? Have you done any research on the matter? We love to help but we're not going to do all the work for you.

Comment: Look into the "VLOOKUP" function, or the "MATCH" function. Try those first, and post a more complete sample of what you tried if you still can't get it to work. (hint: when using a new function, work on a smaller set of data first so you can see what it's doing)

Comment: @maximilian Rosenthal, Don't forget to give feedback on the answers you receive and mark one as accepted if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that your raw data is in a different sheet ("Sheet1").

Have the VLOOKUP in sheet2 like this:

[image: Excel]
The ID in A8 in my example, the formula in B8:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8;Sheet1!C2:AL250;36)
```

Since my language settings are in dutch my delimiter is `;`, if the code above does't work try this one:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,Sheet1!C2:AL250,36)
```

I've changed the delimiter to `,`. You can paste this formula on any sheet, set it up like explained above. Then change the name "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet with the data.

Hope it helped!